# How to filter Multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, multidimensional-array

I have this array.

How can I filter the array of `contacts`?

I want to remove the object which has the value of `participantSetting.excistence == false`

I am using node js, This is my code:

```
schedule.get('/conference/schedule_participants/:circle/:schedId', function(req, res) {
  if(req.schedId){
    getParticipants( req.params, function(contacts){
      results.contacts=contacts;

           var filtered = results(function(c) {
              return c.contacts.participantSetting.existence;
          });
            res.json(filtered);
    }); 
  }else{
          var filtered = results(function(c) {
              return c.contacts.participantSetting.existence;
          });
            res.json(filtered);
  }
});
```

So the output should be

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: You are not returning the filtered response `res.json(results);` should be `res.son(filtered);`

Comment: You've edited your question to exactly what I've posted as answer. What's up?

Comment: You should not edit the question as per the answer, you can add comments on the answer or add new section in the question as `EDIT` or `UPDATE` and explain the scenario

Comment: Hello @Buzinas that is my original code. . and that doesn't work either.

Comment: @Agent69 What is the `results` function, add the code of it

Comment: @Agent69 Look at the answer below, how he as added new section `Update`, you should be doing this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `filter` is already correct, but you must send the variable you set, and not `results` anymore:

```
res.json(filtered);
```

The `Array.prototype.filter` method doesn't change the current array.

It creates a new array with the filtered items.

---

**Update III**

Sorry, trying to answer fast, I didn't realize that you were not using the `filter` function correctly, nor that the `results` is an object, not an array. And also that the `filter` method won't work at all in this scenario. So, below, there is a working solution for you:

```
results.contacts = results.contacts.filter(function(c) {
  return c.participantSetting.existence;
});
res.json(results);
```

Comment: @Andy you're right. I thought he was, because I answered a similar question to him ~an hour ago.

Comment: Do you think `filter` will work, because I see from the above screenshot `results` is an _object_, not _array_

Comment: And now, `filtered` will only contain `contacts` from `result`, I presume OP wants `schedSettings` and other elements from original object too :) which you can confirm from the second screenshot

Comment: @Tushar yeah, I was just thinking about that, and already updated the answer for the third time :(

Comment: (y) One more thing, you don't need extra variable `contactsFiltered`, you can directly assign the filtered contacts to the contacts in the `result`

Comment: I thought `schedSetting` will also remove but it doesn't :D Thanks @Buzinas

Comment: @Agent69 If you want to use the code in this answer, don't forget to remove `results.contacts=contacts;` and rename the `contacts` param in the callback function to `results`.

Comment: @Agent69 You're Welcome :)